# F# Lambdas in records

Tags: f#

I have a simple type:

```
type p =
    {
        desc : string;
        desc2: string
    }
```

How can I pass to a value an anonymous function returning a string instead of a proper string?
The following does not compile. Thanks

```
let oo =
    {
        desc = "ok";
        desc2 = (fun () -> "")
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, I'm a total newb in F#, but my guess is that you're assigning a function to a string, which does not make a whole lot of sense. You can either modify `desc2` to be a function, like

> `desc2 : unit -> string`

or assign a string by calling the anonymous function, i.e.

> `desc2 = (fun () -> "") ()`

Depending on the case that you actually need.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you meant to call the function:

let oo =
    {
        desc = "ok";
        desc2 = (fun () -> "") ()
    }